# Pandas to_xml() Setting xml prefix

Tags: python, pandas, xml, prefix

I'm trying to write xml from pandas dataframe using pd.to_xml() and getting the below output:

code:

```
# Write pandas dataframe to custom xml format

namespaces = {
    'ns0': "urn:sca:com:edi:mappings:aust:b2be:inbounddeliverydate"
}

with open('Inb.xml', 'w') as myfile: 
  myfile.write(data.to_xml(index=False, 
                            root_name='MT_InboundDeliveryDate', 
                            row_name='Row', 
                            namespaces=namespaces, 
                            prefix='ns0'))
```

Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<ns0:MT_InboundDeliveryDate xmlns:ns0="urn:sca:com:edi:mappings:aust:b2be:inbounddeliverydate">
  <ns0:Row>
    <ns0:InboundID>355555106537455</ns0:InboundID>
    <ns0:DocumentDate/>
    <ns0:LFDAT>19082022</ns0:LFDAT>
  </ns0:Row>
  <ns0:Row>
    <ns0:InboundID>35555552066774536</ns0:InboundID>
    <ns0:DocumentDate/>
    <ns0:LFDAT>03012023</ns0:LFDAT>
  </ns0:Row>
</ns0:MT_InboundDeliveryDate>
```

However, I need prefix to apply only to the root_name and not each row

Required Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<ns0:MT_InboundDeliveryDate xmlns:ns0="urn:sca:com:edi:mappings:aust:b2be:inbounddeliverydate">
  <Row>
    <InboundID>355555106537455</InboundID>
    <DocumentDate/>
    <LFDAT>19082022</LFDAT>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <InboundID>35555552066774536</InboundID>
    <DocumentDate/>
    <LFDAT>03012023</LFDAT>
  </Row>
</ns0:MT_InboundDeliveryDate>
```

I want to achieve the above desired output to automate my system update script.

Answer (score 1):

The fix was simple:

```
namespaces = {
    "ns0":"urn:sca:com:edi:mappings:aust:b2be:inbounddeliverydate"
}

with open('Inb.xml', 'w') as myfile: 
  myfile.write(data.to_xml(index=False,
                            row_name="Row",
                            root_name=QName(namespaces["ns0"],'MT_InboundDeliveryDate')))
```